# Incorrect values being displayed in votes cast section

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, activity-dropdown

It seems that votes cast count seems to be wrong in the profile popup as well as in the votes cast section on the user profile page.

I cast only one vote today (December 01). That is correct. And the month shows the correct count as well.

However, the votes cast in this week is wrong. I am sure that I cast few more votes than just 1 during this week.

[image: Votes cast]

The same seems to be the case in the Votes Cast section on the user profile page.

[image: Votes cast section]

Comment: Whether this is actually *wrong* is subject to interpretation. I would be more weirded out by the "month" display having less votes than the "week" one

Comment: @Pekka Well, even in that case it's inconsistent with the reputation line above, which does indeed have the month value < week value.

Comment: @Pekka - May be, you are correct about the interpretation. My interpretation was that `reputation` seems to use different logic in displaying the values under week and month columns whereas `votes cast` seem to have a different logic. In comparison with reputation, votes cast seem to be wrong.

Comment: Siva - yeah. Although @Tim has a point, I didn't notice that.

Comment: @Pekka Me thinks month votes are less than week because of the new month that's rolled in?

Comment: @Sathya I think Pekka was just noting that people instinctively assume that a month total will be greater than or equal to a week total, and it requires that extra "Oh right, a new month began in the middle of the week" revelation to reconcile the reverse case. But resetting the "week" just because the month flipped over would certainly be more confusing, anyway.

Comment: I believe all counts are reset at the start of a new calendar month.

Comment: @AnnaLear - Reputation is not reset. Please note that the reputation in the activity dropdown shows 260 for the week and 25 for the month. When you say `counts`, do you mean only votes, favorites and revisions and not the reputation?

Comment: @Siva Yes, I meant everything except reputation. Reputation works differently. I'm not 100% sure I'm right, though.

Comment: @AnnaLear - I realize I am late to the party, but I just noticed this over at GISse.  If it is possible to have reputation counts not be reset for the week, why not all counts?  Since it is relatively rare for a month and week to end at the same time, the odds are good that someone will see their vote counts reset midway during the week.  This seems confusing.

Answer (score 2):

This profile overlay has gone away in favor of the [new top bar](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/a-new-top-bar-for-stack-exchange/).