# "Votes cast - week" seem to show only votes in this month?

Tags: bug, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Incorrect values being displayed in votes cast section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114292/incorrect-values-being-displayed-in-votes-cast-section)

Here is an example from stackoverflow, from today - thursday Dec 1st:

```
            today   week    month
reputation  35      192     35
votes cast  11      11      11
```

I casted some votes yesterday so it seems that "votes cast / week" show only my today's votes.
It's not a feature because in case of reputation it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that the casted votes shown in a group are shown for the other groups too.
This week's votes should show the votes casted between midnight of November 27 (UTC time) and midnight of December 3 (excluded), since the SE week starts with Sunday, and ends with Saturday. This month's votes should just include the votes casted since midnight of December first.

In my case, the shown votes were 6 for all the groups, and when I voted this question they have been all increased to 7. I know I voted in the past days; therefore, my votes for this month cannot be equal to the votes for the current week.

Comment: ok, you just state that it's a problem too. I'll retag to bug and let's wait for an answer.